# Is it possible to select $(this) AND use selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm wondering if I can use $(this) as well as a class selector before running a function on them.

So rather than doing;

```
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$('.closed').toggleClass('open');
```

Do something more like;

```
$(this, '.closed').toggleClass('open');
```

Whereas really, the above will select 'this' within the context of '.closed'

Regards,

Comment: Ignore my (deleted) answer, misread question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$(".closed").add(this).toggleClass("open");
```

It will add `this` element to the set of matched elements (i.e. `.closed`).

Comment: Excellent answer, +1 :) Also, if element has id, you can do something like this. (I would have done this before knowing your approach)

`$('#' + this.id + ',.closed').toggleClass('open');`

Comment: I would have used Jashwant's solution normally, but I find it quite ugly. As for VisioN's .. I like that! Any idea which of those two solutions is faster?

Comment: @Joel They should run almost the same speed. However, [jsperf shows](http://jsperf.com/add-vs-multiselector) that `add()` solution is slightly (4%) slower than multiple selector. By all means, using `add()` is the only way of how to add `this` to the set of jQuery elements.

Comment: What an ideal answer. Thank you.